# Zend framework ignores custom helper path in application.ini

Tags: zend-framework, zend-view

I have my view helper in `Library/My/View/Helper/LoadSkin.php`, I added this line in application.ini : `resources.view.helperPath.My_View_Helper = "My/View/Helper"` but I'm still getting

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Loader_PluginLoader_Exception' with message 
'Plugin by name 'LoadSkin' was not found in the registry; used paths: Zend_View_Helper_: Zend/View
/Helper/;C:/Program Files (x86)/Zend/Apache2/htdocs/TinOuzel/application/views\helpers/'
```

This looks like ZF stills looks for helper in default path ;/

My namespacje is registered in bootstrap:

```
protected function _initAutoloader ()
{
    $autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
    $autoloader->registerNamespace('My_');
    $autoloader->suppressNotFoundWarnings(true);
    return $autoloader;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in this case , you must had overridden  the default view object

in much clear example ,  you are using something like :

`$view = new Zend_View();`

mostly  somewhere  in your bootstrap file , just remove it and you would be okay

Comment: Thanks, but ther's another problem, I use this helper for loading skin data and I want select active skin by $view->skin = "skinName". In bootstrap this method works but in ini file I cannot use resources.view.skin = 'skinName" because skin isn't plugin, is there any way to add custom properties to view in ini?